# Translate "Account Information" Block content in Magento Order page

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, localisation, admin-panel, customer-attribute

I figured out that in the Order detail page the "Account Information" block has the last two lines that are not being translated on language selector change.
They always remain in english.

In my case the two labels are "Date of birth" and "Tax/Vat Number".

I tried to open

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/info.phtml
```

and i figured out that the last two lines are called by a foreach function:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCustomerAccountData() as $data):?>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label><?php echo $data['label'] ?></label></td>
<td class="value"><strong><?php echo $data['value'] ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Any idea on how to translate that to labels?

Answer (score 2):

These are attribute labels, so they can be stored in the database with different values per store view. But unfortunately, Magento CE only allows product attribute configuration in the admin panel, not customer attribute configuration.

You have two options:

1. Save the store specific label directly in the `eav_attribute_label` table
2. Change the template to use translation:

   ```
   <?php echo $this->__($data['label']) ?>
   ```

   and add missing translations to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/[locale]/translate.csv`, for example:

   ```
   "Mage_Sales::Date of birth","Geburtsdatum"
   "Mage_Sales::Tax/Vat Number","Ust.-ID"
   ```